# MySQL ORDER BY returning incorrect results based on datetime query

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am getting behaviour with some MySQL queries that I don't understand

I am running MySQL 5.5.42

**WHAT I HAVE**

I have a table with columns:

- id (int, auto increment)
- party_id (int - set by back end when adding a row)
- added_on (datetime - set by back end when adding a row i.e. I don't use ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

**WHAT I WANT TO DO**

I want to carry out the following queries:

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE party_id = 1 ORDER BY added_on ASC

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE party_id IN (1,2,3...) ORDER BY added_on ASC

The strange behaviour occurs when added_on dates are the same for the same party_id (as above, added_on dates are set by the backend and not MySQL)

For example:

- id = 100
- party_id = 1
- added_on = 2015-10-12 00:00:00

and

- id = 101
- party_id = 1
- added_on = 2015-10-12 00:00:00

When I run this query (SELECT * FROM my_table **WHERE party_id = 1** ORDER BY added_on ASC) the results returned are in the order id = 100 then id = 101 (which is the order they were added on despite the date being the same).

When I run this query (SELECT * FROM my_table **WHERE IN (1,2,3,4,5)** ORDER BY added_on ASC) the results returned are in the order of added_on and where added_on is the same then the lowest id (100) comes first as above.

**MY PROBLEM**

When I run the query with **WHERE party_id IN (1,2,3,4,5...89)** (89 or over) then the results returned are in order of added_on BUT where added_on is the same the results are reversed - so in the example above for party_id of 1 the results return id = 101 and then id = 100

Note that it doesn't need to be id = 89 it just needs to be 89+ IDs I am querying in "party_id IN (...)"

**WHAT I HAVE TESTED**

I thought it might be a microtime issue but both times give me .000000 as the microtime plus - as I said above - I am using the same added_on date when I insert the row, so they should be exactly the same.

I have manually checked these queries in phpMyAdmin too and get the same results. I originally thought it was either an issue with the back end code or framework I am using, but it seems not.

Any ideas of where I am going wrong?

Comment: _“Any ideas of where I am going wrong?”_ – you’re going wrong in expecting data to be ordered in a certain why, without telling the database to order by that specific criterion. Since you are not telling the database in what order you want the ids for the same added_on date, you can not expect them to be ordered in any certain way. If you get them in the order they were inserted in for certain queries/selections, that is just pure coincidence. If you _want_ them ordered, you need to _tell_ the database to order them for you.

Comment: OK thanks for that. I didn't realise it was a coincidence. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @CBroe. It is right not to expect the data to be in a certain way, but shouldn't it be the _same_ in both cases (whatever the order)? Why the order for the second query is reversed then the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just add second order columnn `id`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE party_id IN (1,2,3,89) 
ORDER BY added_on ASC, id ASC
```

Comment: You not ORDER BY added_on you only ORDER BY id ASc. So id is AUTOINC that mean a higher number is a later time